# Replace apache envvars with sed command

Tags: apache, sed

Hi Guys I am a newbie with sed editor and I need to replace the follow line on my envvars file:

current line

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
```

I need to replace to

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=admin
```

I tried

```
sed -i "s/export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data/export APACHE_RUN_USER=nbadmin/"envvars
```

This does not work. There is a space between the word export and apache.
Can please someone help with this sed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are missing a space after `nbadmin/"envvars`. Should be `nbadmin/" envvars`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the space before your filename.

Comment: Yes, I know that fedorqui was the one who actually answered that, but this question should be closed.